# Parse.com Background Push Notification Not Run

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send a background push notification through Parse.com that pings my server:

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
            [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];
    }

    NSString *CustomData = [userInfo objectForKey:@"CustomField"];

    // ping server to confirm the push notification is delivered, sometimes this is called but not always
    [[DAL sharedInstance] log:CustomData onComplete:nil];

    // do stuff
    if([CustomData isEqualToString:@"CustomItem"])
    {
            // do stuff
    }
```

When I send a push notification through Parse.com's REST API to https://api.parse.com/1/push with

```
{ "where":{"objectId":"[objectID]"}, "data":{"alert":"test","content-available":"1","CustomField":"CustomItem"} }
```

I get the alert and the server is pinged, but if I remove the alert

```
{ "where":{"objectId":"[objectID]"}, "data":{"content-available":"1","CustomField":"CustomItem"} }
```

nothing happens and the server is not pinged. How can I send the push notification invisibly and still ping the server?